# C Programming - How to write a char into char*

Tags: c, lex

Writing a character to the stream is ensured by several functions in C, such as :

```
 int fputc ( int character, FILE * stream );
 int putchar ( int character );
 int putc ( int character, FILE * stream );
...
```

My question is simple : is there any function which provide  the possibility to write a character into a `char*`? (`callback(int character, char * stream)`)

**update**
:to explain more my problem
i'am using lex/yacc compiling solution.
 input() funcion returns the next character in the stream .I want to store for a specified condition the whole stream returned by this function into a variable.

Comment: do you mean append a character to a null terminated string in a char*? You do realize that you'd need to allocate more memory?

Comment: exactly , I am really confused .the problem is i can't exactly specify at the beginning the whole size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since pointer arithmetic is in the very nature of C, there are no such functions. To put a character into some memory pointed to by `stream` and advance it, you would do:

```
*stream++ = character;
```

At the next sequence point `stream` will be pointing to the new, still unwritten character.

Of course, make sure that you don't advance `stream` beyond the bounds of its allocated area. To prevent this from happening you could do a simple calculation:

```
if (stream - base > BUFFER_SIZE) /* stop */
```

`base` would be a pointer to the beginning of the allocated area, the initial value of `stream`.

Comment: @Shiplu: not that dangerous if you know what you are doing.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev As i understood from your response i should before specify the arbitrary allocated area(and this is my problem).If you don't mind plz explain how to reinitialize the pointer to the begening of the allocated memory.THNKS FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: @Aymanadou: after you have reached the end of the buffer, simply saying `stream = base` will rewind the `stream` pointer to the beginning. Of course, make sure that you have flushed the old contents of the buffer since you are starting to overwrite it. Allocating more memory whenever you fill the buffer could be done, but is generally not the way it should be done.

Answer (score 2):

Why not directly access the pointer:

```
*stream = character;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, try `snprintf` if you need a function.

```
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
char c = 'x';
snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%c", c);
```

If you're willinig to convert your char to a string first, you can also use `strcat`, `strcpy` etc.

Comment: That's WAY too much overhead just for putting a single byte.

Comment: i can't exactly specify at the beginning the whole size of the buffer.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev I agree, but he asked for a function. I'd just put it into the buffer myself.